# bash script that gives basic multiplication problems, input needs to be correct

Tags: bash, scripting

Years ago I had written a program in `qbasic` that would generate a random multiplication question with each operand between 1 and 10, then it would prompt the user for the correct answer.  When they got it right it would say so, otherwise it would say "Wrong" or similar and ask them to try again.  In my original version if they got it wrong I'd ask them for 2 numbers and print the product of those.

Since I no longer have `DOS` or `qbasic` available, I would like to rewrite this in `bash` for my granddaughter.

This is close to what I want in `qbasic`:

```
TABLAS: PRINT "Esos son los tablas"
RANDOMIZE TIMER
CLS
FOR i = 0 TO 100
x = INT(RND * 10) + 1 'if you want say only 9s or only 7s, change
'this to x=9  or x=7 ...
y = INT(RND * 10) + 1
PRINT x; "X"; y; "=";
INPUT "", n
IF x * y <> n THEN
    PRINT "NOT CORRECT"
    INPUT "Entra el primero numero: ", a
    INPUT "Entra el segundo numero: ", b
    PRINT "Respuesta corecto es: "; a * b 'now I am closer, on the
    'previous that I sent 'you  I had forgotten the b on this line.
ELSE
    PRINT "CORRECT"
    PRINT
END IF
```

Comment: Do you know any `bash` already?  Have you tried anything so far?  One thing that will likely help you along the way is that in `bash` you can access `$RANDOM` to get a random int, then use the `%` mod operator to get it into the range you want, similar to how you're doing the `x` and `y` initialization in `qbasic`

Comment: Um ... it kind of sounds like you want someone to write it for you. That is not what we do here. You have the logic down; you want to translate it to bash. So, learn some bash. If you have a specific question like "How do I do x in bash", and you tried to find it yourself first, go ahead and ask that kind of question.

Comment: "...  I would like to rewrite this in bash ..." ... Uh... that would not be my first choice. Or any of my choices.

Comment: @Eric Renouf  : Thank you, I do know a little on bash, but very little,like I said, I have looked, and been reading some tutorials. I did try this:

Comment: You may have read the wrong tutorial because this is not `bash` syntax (at all)